# Does Git suitable for binary file storage?

Tags: git, binary

Background:
Git doesn't support access permission on folder level, but in my company, different developer have different access permission on source code.

Solution:
As we choose Azure DevOps as our ALM, so we decide to make each common module split from customer project. each module has its own source code Git repo, all module lib files are stored in a Git repo, Git repo for customer project use submodule to reference common module libs.

Each time source code of a common module is changed, user need manually compile code into a lib, and check it in module lib repository.

My question:
1.Will module lib repository be very big after frequently checkin?
2.If this is not a good practice, Can you give me some advice?

detailed see attached picture.[detailed description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERy34.jpg)

Comment: Your question is too vague. What exactly are these binary files? If on Linux, what is the output of the [file(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command on them? On which operating system? How did you obtain them? What will happen to you if you lose these files? Can you afford some remote backup e.g. using [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) or [scp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html)? If no, why?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "module"? Did you consider storing your data in some [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) database?

Comment: Don't comment your question, but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65696424/edit) it to improve it. And please give some [mre], e.g. some C source code. Explain why you need to keep libraries in `.git` and why you cannot recompile their C source code. [git](http://git-scm.com/) has been designed for source code.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, it is not a good practice to keep binaries in remote git like Github. You can use artifactory to keep binaries and then you can also manage them well. I used https://jfrog.com/ in the past to keep binaries.